# NSURLRequest not posting values to a Codeigniter API

Tags: ios, objective-c, api, codeigniter

Good day,

I am trying to use a Codeigniter based API to connect with iOS and using NSURLRequest. 
The API is in debugMode and for now it returns the same key value pair as json as the one that you are posting. I have tried posting the values to the link through postman and it works correctly, however when I post it through my iOS application, the json response is received but the array that should contain the post values is empty.

Here is the iOS Code snippet :

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",BASEURL,service]];

NSMutableURLRequest * request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

NSURLConnection *connection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

NSString * params = @"authkey=waris";
NSData * postData = [params dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)[postData length]];

[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];;
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

NSLog(@"Posting : '%@'  to %@",params,url);

[connection start];
```

This is the response when I post the same parameters through postman ( A RESTFUL Client for Chrome )

```
{
"status": "1",
"data": {
    "authkey": "warisali"
  }
}
```

However when I query the same API from the above iOS Code I am getting this :

```
{
  data = 0;
  status = 1;
}
```

Any help on the matter will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Check whether you are actually receiving key/value pairs at server end

Comment: Yes. Thats the actual reason. I am not receiving key/value pair from iOS. I receive them when I post the same key/value pair from any other client . Although the response is being get from iOS which means the URL and the connectivity is ok.

Comment: BTW, it's unnecessary to set the content length header of the request, as `NSURLConnection` does that for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the ASIHttpRequest + SBJson combo and that worked like Charm!

After adding the ASIHttpRequest core classes and SBJson Classes to parse the JSON, I was able to achieve what I wanted !

Comment: It's fine that you found a work-around, but generally I'd advise an actively supported framework, such as [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking), rather than the discontinued ASIHttpRequest.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue (not with CodeIgniter but with Ruby ...) 
Try something like this, solved my problem.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",BASEURL,service]];

NSMutableURLRequest * request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

NSURLConnection *connection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

NSDictionary *paramDict = @{@"authkey": @"waris"};
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:paramDict options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];

if (error)
{
    NSLog(@"error while creating data %@", error);
    return;
}

    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)[postData length]];

[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];;
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

NSLog(@"Posting : '%@'  to %@",params,url);

[connection start];
```

Comment: Thanks I ended up using the ASIHTTPRequest + SBJson Combo and that worked like charm!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that because of the way you're creating the connection, it will start immediately, before you've finished configuring the request. Thus, you're creating a mutable request, creating and starting the connection, then attempting to modify the request and then trying to start the request a second time.

You can fix that by changing the line that says:

```
NSURLConnection *connection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

To say:

```
NSURLConnection *connection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:NO];
```

Or, easier, just move the original instantiation of the `NSURLConnection` (without the `startImmediately:NO`) after you've finished configuring your request, and then eliminate the `[connection start]` line altogether.